# Sentiment analysis with Lambda Expressions in Python

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, generic-lambda

I'm trying to use TextBlob to perform sentiment analysis in Power BI. I'd like to use a lamdba expression because it seems to be substantially faster than running an iterative loop in Power BI.

For example, using Text Blob:

```
dataset['Polarity Score'] =dataset['Comment'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(str(x).lower()).sentiment.polarity)
```

creates a Power BI data column named "Polarity Score" that has the numerical values from TextBlob.

I would like to do similar withe the TextBlob.classify() function. However, I don't know how to pass it the second argument of the classifier.

Tutorials show to create and use a classifier:

```
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
from textblob import TextBlob

cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
blob = TextBlob("The beer is good. But the hangover is horrible.", classifier=cl)
blob.classify()
```

I've tried

```
dataset['Polarity Class'] =dataset['Comment'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(str(x).lower()).classify(), classifier=cl)
```

and

```
dataset['Polarity Class'] =dataset['Comment'].apply(lambda x,y: TextBlob(str(x).lower()).classify(), y=cl)
```

Neither work and point to the way I'm passing the classifier. How would I pass the classifier parameter in a lambda expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
dataset['Polarity Class'] = dataset['Comment'].apply(
    lambda x: TextBlob(str(x).lower(), classifier=cl).classify()
)
```

Or if you want to refactor the possibly confusing lambda expression out,

```
cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)

def classify(x):
    return TextBlob(str(x).lower(), classifier=cl).classify()

dataset['Polarity Class'] = dataset['Comment'].apply(classify)
```

is equivalent.